# Moving raw data from single column to adjacent columns using based off other cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and have come up short teaching myself over the last 6 months to solve a problem at work and would greatly appreciate any help I could get.

I am having trouble moving test data from a single column into the appropriate columns. At first I tried sorting and simply using copy and paste with an offset but then realized that the test do not always show up in the same order or are not present at all so if either of those conditions are true then the data does not go to its appropriate column. After that I tried a loop, which I assume is the solution, but the data is just copied and pasted seemingly randomly.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Example

```
Raw
Id Test Result
1  A    1.1
1  B    1.2
2  A    2.1
2  C    2.3
3  B    3.2
1  C    1.3

Desired
Id  A    B    C
1   1.1  1.2  1.3
2   2.1       2.3
3        3.2
```

Images of the actual data
[image: Raw Data]

Desired Output
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: You can use a Pivot Table, either the classic or using Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try helper & formula to do it as picture show.